# Undo rollback in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have called rollback in laravel 7 by mistake and my table is gone. Is there any way to bring my table back?

I had written php artisan migrate:rollback

Comment: run `migrate` again, but the data is gone

Comment: Depends, was there data in the table? If yes, let's hope you have backups.

Comment: @Jerodev Thanks, mate. No there was no data in the table luckily as I'm a beginner and learning laravel